# How to select a partition key for for a DynamoDB query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have created a dynamo db table with name- "sample".It has below columns. CreatedDate will have creation time of any records inserted to this table.

```
Itemid,
ItemName,
ItemDescription,
CreatedDate,
UpdatedDate
```

I am creating a python-flask based rest api which always fetches last 100 records inserted to this table. This API (python-flask function) does not have any input parameters. It should just return the last records inserted to this table.

**Question 1**

What should be the partition key for this table? I am using the boto3 library to fetch records from DynamoDB. I prefer not to do scan operation because it may cause performance issues. If I use the query function it asks for a partition key. Since this rest API does not accept any input I am not sure how to use it.

**Question 2**

Has anyone faced similar situation? And what was done to fix this?

Note: I am pretty much newbie to DynamoDB, NoSQL and Boto

Answer (score 2):

To query your table using `CreatedDate` without knowing the `ItemId`, you can use Global Secondary Index write sharding by adding an attribute (e.g., `ShardId`) containing a (0-N) value to every item that you will use for the global secondary index partition key.

Depending on how your items are distributed against `CreatedDate`, you can set the `ShardId` so that it is likely to have evenly distributed access patterns. For example: `YYYY`, `YYYYMM` or `YYYYMMDD`. Then, you create a global secondary index with `ShardId` as an index partition key and `CreatedDate` as an index sort key.

Knowing the primary key for your GSI (since the `ShardId` value is derived from `CreatedDate`), you can query the table for the 100 most recent items with query's **Limit** parameter (or **LastEvaluatedKey** if your items set size is larger than 1 MB of data).

See [Using Global Secondary Index Write Sharding for Selective Table Queries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-gsi-sharding.html).

Comment: If suppose ShardId is created in such a way that it is in format - Date_number (where number can be 0 to N). There can be multiple records created for a day with different ShardId starting with date of that day. When i query using secondary index is there a provision to query based on ShardId starting with a specific date? (something like a contain or starts-with function )

Comment: Or can we have partition key for GSI to have same value for all records without creating hot spot while querying? If yes then i can fetch it based on one GSI partition key and use limit for 100 records.

Comment: @codinglover: (1) You must always specify the partition key name and value as an _equality_ condition. (2) I don't think you can do that without creating hot partitions.

Comment: In that case how can we achieve the requirement which i mentioned in original post without creating hot partitions?

Comment: @codinglover As I mentioned, you select a value for `ShardId` that you already know from the `CreatedDate` such as `2018`, `201804` or `20180423` (depending on how your items are distributed).